# Content Author /editor help view with gif animation in sitecore cms

Tags: sitecore-client

Is there module in sitecore market place where help text is extended to include any gif image  or animation image or screenshot to educate content author about specific field behavior or content behavior?

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Sitecore you are using but there is a module that supports uploading videos to show in the Page Editor (now Experience Editor), it says it only supports up to 6.5 though so I'm unsure if it will work for later versions of Sitecore.

The module extends the inbuilt Help Template that ships with Sitecore and adds a new field called 'Help Videos'.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/P/Page_Editor_Help.aspx?sc_lang=en

It might give you some ideas though on how to approach this. Other than this module I think you would need to build something custom to do this.

Where do you want to show this extra info - Experience Editor or Content Editor?

It will probably be easier to do this in Experience Editor.

You could do something like this to add a custom button and then link that to a modal popup that passes the component id and loads in a video/text/image etc with additional help for that component perhaps:

http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2016/05/How-to-customize-the-Sitecore-Experience-Editor.aspx

Comment: No problem. can you provide more info on where you want to show these animations/gifs etc though as I mentioned above and ARURA said? If you can we may be able to help you further.